# Unknown parameter in GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0]: "BillingMode", must be one of: IndexName, KeySchema, Projection, ProvisionedThroughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How do you set a DynamoDB Global Secondary Index to "Pay Per Use" when using the Python boto3 API?

I tried setting `'BillingMode': 'PAY_PER_REQUEST'`, which works fine when creating a table.

However when trying the same in a GSI, I get:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in GlobalSecondaryIndexes[0]: "BillingMode", must be one of: IndexName, KeySchema, Projection, ProvisionedThroughput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the billing mode directly/independently on a GSI.

> Global secondary indexes inherit the read/write capacity mode from the base table.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html